# OpenVPN : web pages won't load

Tags: openvpn

My setup :

- Router : Unifi USG local IP `10.1.1.1/32`, port `1194/udp` forwarded to `10.1.1.20:1194`
- Unraid server with Docker containers on it.
- OpenVPN container ([kylemanna/openvpn](https://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/openvpn)) installed on the embedded MacVlan network, IP address `10.1.1.20/32`. I did this way because my other containers are all in this way. The container is configured to hand out IP addresses in the `192.168.255.0/24` subnet.
- I have added `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.1.1.2"` which is my local Pi-Hole with local DNS configured.

From my client (windows 10 machine in a local network different from the local network where the OpenVPN service is), I can connect to the VPN and get an IP address as expected (i.e. I get `192.168.0.5`). Once connected:

- I can ping my other containers both by IP or by hostname registered in PiHole (i.e. `ping 10.1.1.11` and `ping service.local`)
- I can access the Web UI of those services also both by IP and by hostname. Speed is very good (both clients have 1Gbps fiber :))
- I can ping public IP such as `ping 1.1.1.1` or `ping 8.8.8.8`
- I can ping domains such as `ping google.com`
- If I do a `tracert 8.8.8.8`, the first hop is `192.168.255.1` and the second is `10.1.1.1`, then it goes to my ISP. All as expected.

But... When I try to load a webpage, it does not work and ends up in `An error occurred during a connection to serverfault.com. PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR`

From the default config file generated by the container, I only added 3 lines in the `openvpn.conf` on the server side:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.131.10.2"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0"
```

My `*.ovpn` on client side :

```
client
nobind
dev tun
remote-cert-tls server
remote openvpn.example.com 1194 udp
<key>
-----PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<cert>
-----CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<ca>
-----CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
-----OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
redirect-gateway def1
```

my `openvpn.conf` on server side

```
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 4
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/openvpn.example.com.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/openvpn.example.com.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log
user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no
### Route Configurations Below
route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0
### Push Configurations Below
push "block-outside-dns"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.1.1.2"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "comp-lzo no"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0"
```

Where should I look for a solution?